# Django error: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.10 and python 3.4

The precise error is

```
NoReverseMatch at /movies/movie/Twilight/
Reverse for 'movie-details' with arguments '(8,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['movies/movie/(?P<movie_id>\\d+)|(?P<movie_name>[a-zA-Z\\ ]+)/$']
```

The error is caused by this line: `{% url 'moviesrating:movie-details' movie.id %}` in template *moviesrating/select_movie.html*

In file *moviesrating/urls.py*, which is correctly included in the main urls file, there are those lines:

```
app_name = 'moviesrating'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^movie/(?P<movie_id>\d+)|(?P<movie_name>[a-zA-Z\ ]+)/$', view_movie, name = 'movie-details'),
]
```

which refers to function *view_movie* in *moviesrating/views.py*:

```
def view_movie(request, movie_id, movie_name):
    if movie_id:
        movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk = movie_id)
    elif movie_name:
        try:
            movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, name = movie_name)
        except MultipleObjectsReturned: # There are two movies named 'Twilight'
            movies = get_list_or_404(Movie, name = movie_name)
            return render(request, "moviesrating/select_movie.html", {'movies': movies})
    else:
        movie = None
    return render(request, "moviesrating/movie.html", {'movie': movie})
```

The purpose of the url */movies/movie/...* is to show a movie found by name or by id, the specific url pattern comes from this need.

The point is that the error shows that **even if it doesn't find the reverse match it finds the right url pattern** so I thought the pattern didn't match. Then I tried to change the line to:

```
{% url 'moviesrating:movie-details' movie.id %}
{% url 'moviesrating:movie-details' movie_id=movie.id movie_name=None %}
{% url 'moviesrating:movie-details' movie.id None %}
{% url 'moviesrating.views.view_movie' movie.id %}
{% url 'moviesrating.views.view_movie' movie_id=movie.id %}
{% url 'moviesrating.views.view_movie' movie_id=movie.id movie_name=None %}
```

but none of them worked.

Viewing the link in the browser (ex. *http://localhost:8081/movies/movie/8*) works, so it's not that page that causes the problem.

At this point really I can't understand the problem, I've followed the passages explained in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#s-removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates) and read a lot of questions already asked but none of them solved my problem.

If something is unclear or more information is needed please let me know and I will edit the post. Thanks

Here is the full stacktrace of the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8081/movies/movie/Twilight/

Django Version: 1.10.1
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'todolist.apps.TodolistConfig',
 'moviesrating.apps.MoviesratingConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\fra\Programmazione\Python\myserver\moviesrating\templates\moviesrating\select_movie.html, error at line 12
   Reverse for 'movie-details' with arguments '(8,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['movies/movie/(?P<movie_id>\\d+)|(?P<movie_name>[a-zA-Z\\ ]+)/$']   2 : <html>
   3 : <head>
   4 : <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   5 : <title>Choice your movie</title>
   6 : </head>
   7 : <body>
   8 : <h2>Choice of which movie named {{ movies.0.name }} would you see the details</h2>
   9 : 
   10 : <ul>
   11 : {% for movie in movies %}
   12 :     <li> {% url 'moviesrating:movie-details' movie.id %} </li>
   13 :     <li><a href="{{ movie_url }}">{{ movie.name }} del {{ movie.year }} diretto da {{ movie.director }}</a></li>
   14 : {% endfor %}
   15 : </ul>
   16 : </body>
   17 : </html>
   18 : 

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\fra\Programmazione\Python\myserver\moviesrating\views.py" in view_movie
  31.             movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, name = movie_name)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in get_object_or_404
  85.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  389.             (self.model._meta.object_name, num)

During handling of the above exception (get() returned more than one Movie -- it returned 2!), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\fra\Programmazione\Python\myserver\moviesrating\views.py" in view_movie
  34.             return render(request, "moviesrating/select_movie.html", {'movies': movies})

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  439.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /movies/movie/Twilight/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'movie-details' with arguments '(8,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['movies/movie/(?P<movie_id>\\d+)|(?P<movie_name>[a-zA-Z\\ ]+)/$']
```

Comment: It appears as though the url is allowing either a movie name or a movie id, but your view is expecting both. I imagine you could solve this issue by insisting that the url contain both id and name.

Comment: I'll try but I want have the possibility to chose which I want to insert, if the id or the name

Comment: Why not have one parameter called movie_name that can be any combination of alpha numeric and then in your view check if it's numeric then it's a movie id and if it's strictly alpha, it's a movie name.

Comment: I deleted that comment and put one in that I think you'll find more helpful. Please see the one before yours.

Comment: Maybe try changing your view definition to: `def view_movie(request, movie_id, movie_name=None):`

Comment: @MattCremeens give me a minute and I check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's `reverse()` cannot handle disjunctive patterns (using a `|`) outside of a capturing group. It's one of those things you'd hope someone would've fixed somewhere in the past 10 or so years, but this limitation has been around [since 1.0](https://github.com/django/django/blob/978a00e39fee25cfa99065285b0de88366710fad/django/utils/regex_helper.py#L97).

A workaround is to split up the pattern into two patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^movie/(?P<movie_id>\d+)/$', view_movie, name='movie-details'),
    url(r'^movie/(?P<movie_name>[a-zA-Z\ ]+)/$', view_movie, name='movie-details'),
]
```

You'll need to add a default to both parameters:

```
def view_movie(request, movie_id=None, movie_name=None):
    ...
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot, I think this is the fastest way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending one parameter to your view, though it expects two. If you want to stick with one that can be interpreted as an id or a name, why not accept an alpha-numeric parameter

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^movie/(?P<movie_id>[A-z0-9]+)/$', view_movie, name = 'movie-details'),
]
```

and then check in your view which one it is so you know if you should treat it as an id or a name

```
def view_movie(request, movie_id):
     try: 
         int(movie_id)
         movie_name = False
    except:
         movie_name = True

    if not movie_name:
        movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk = movie_id)
    elif movie_name:

    # etc.
```

Comment: Note that the regex will just send `None` for any defined capturing group that isn't matched in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parentheses around capturing groups:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^movie/((?P<movie_id>\d+)|(?P<movie_name>[a-zA-Z\ ]+))/$', view_movie, name = 'movie-details'),
]
```

and add defaults to view parameters:

```
def view_movie(request, movie_id=None, movie_name=None):
    if movie_id:
        return HttpResponse('1')
    if movie_name:
        return HttpResponse('2')
```

Idk why but i've tried this on my project and it works.